# Why only ArrayBlockingQueue and SynchronousQueue have fairness policy?

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer, blockingqueue

Speaking about all classes implementing interface BlockingQueue, only ArrayBlockingQueue and SynchronousQueue have fairness policy.

Besides, it seems that in all other BlockingQueue classes "fairness is false" meaning that any thread blocked first would be unblocked in random order.

*So why ArrayBlockingQueue and SynchronousQueue are so special and distinct from other classes in this respect?*